# Python Selenium: How to select a radio button?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, radio-button

I know this question has been asked previously but none of the previous answers are helping me here.

I need to scrape a table which is generated by selecting one of the radio buttons on this page - https://www.oeko-tex.com/en/business/oeko_tex_certified_products/oeko_tex_certified_products.html

My code so far -

```
driver.get("https://www.oeko-tex.com/en/business/oeko_tex_certified_products/oeko_tex_certified_products.html")
time.sleep(2)
radio = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and @value='step']")    
time.sleep(2)
radio.click()
```

From what I understand, the xpath is not valid here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath you are using is valid. The issue is that the radio button is inside a frame. So you need to switch to that frame and then search for this element.

Add this before searching for the radio button:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

And I would also suggest to use `webdriverwait` instead of `time.sleep` calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked!
Also could you please explain why is webdriverwait better than time.sleep()?

Comment: `time.sleep()` will always(and only) wait for 2 seconds and then go to next line of code. But with `webdriverwait` you can wait for as long as you want(like 60 seconds), but it will go to the next line of code as soon as condition is true(which can be like element is visible/clickable etc.) Read more [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)